# Pass data between viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a viewcontroller and I need to pass an ID to a secondViewController that will be present as page sheet after click a collectionViewCell. I tried to pass the ID using a instance of the secondViewController but that didn't work I tried using segue as well but It didn't work either.

Comment: Can you share part of the code(how did you pass the id) so that we can know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

**Second View Controller**

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

//Add id property
var id: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(id)
    }

}
```

**First View Controller**

```
let secondViewController = initialize your controller
secondViewController.id = data you need to pass
secondViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer solves the problem of pass the id but the ui doesn't show the viewcontroller as pagesheet just makes the animation and put the current viewcontroller behind.